# How to get the file name part from HTML src attribute of <script> tag using Regex pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to get the file name from the src attribute of HTML 'script' tag. I managed to get the value for entire src attribute but not sure how to get only file name including extension. Below is the code with example.

```
        String javaScript = "<script src=\"https://www.xxx.co.uk/rta2/v-0.52.min.js\" class=\"RTA2-loader\" data-hosts=\"ted.xxx.co.uk\"></script>";

        Pattern scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*[\"'](.*?)[\"'][^>]*>");

        Matcher script = scriptPattern.matcher(javaScript);
        if (script.find()) {
            System.out.println(script.group(1));
        }
```

The above one prints https://www.xxx.co.uk/rta2/v-0.52.min.js

Instead of entire URL I want the file name i.e.

v-0.52.min.js

Also it should support '/' and '\' path separator.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
String javaScript = "<script src=\"https://www.xxx.co.uk/rta2/v-0.52.min.js\" class=\"RTA2-loader\" data-hosts=\"ted.xxx.co.uk\"></script>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<script src=\"[^\"]+(?:/|\\\\)([^\"]+)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(javaScript);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String src = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(src);
}
```

The regular expression searches for the literal string `<script src=`
followed by a single double quote character, i.e. `"`
followed by one or more characters that are not the double quote character
followed by either a single forward slash, i.e. `/`, or a single backslash, i.e. `\`
again followed by one or more characters that are not the double quote character (and these characters are placed in a capturing group)
and finally followed by another double quote character.

The above code displays the following:

```
v-0.52.min.js
```

Nonetheless, I wish to point out that using a HTML parser is preferred over regular expressions when it comes to parsing HTML.